# After dd completion, should records In = records out

Tags: linux, unix, windows-8.1, dd

I am using the following cmd where **sda**(500GB) is my laptop hd (unmounted) and **sdc**(500GB) is my external usb hd

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc bs=4096
```

When complete this returns

```
122096647+0 records in
122096646+0 records out
50010782016 bytes (500GB) copied, 10975. 5 s, 45.6 MB/s
```

This shows **records in != records out**

```
fdisk -l
```

returns

```
Device    Boot  Start   End         Blocks      Id  System
/dev/sda1 *     2048    718847      358407      7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       718848  977102847   488192000   7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sdc1 *     2048    718847      358407      7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2       718848  977102847   976384000   7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

This also shows differences between the **Block** sizes

Another question is it normal for *dd* to take 3 hours for a 500GB copy.(laptop ssd to normal non ssd usb hd)

My Physical Sector on windows is *4096* whilst Logical Sector is *512*

Comment: Maybe the question is better suited for [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: @rtur if that is the case can soembody move it, or advise me how I can do so myself?

Answer (score 0):

is it normal for dd to take 3 hours - yes.  dd can take very long because you are copying everything off the drive bit by bit bit.  And you need to recognize how the connection is made from source (sda) to destination (sdc).  You mention sdc is your external usb hard drive, so what is the max transfer speed on USB?  Then, it is unlikely that transfer will always happen at that max value.  If it is USB 2.0 then yes, it can take very long.

Which is why i hate dd.  It is often used when it should not be, and differences between source and destination such as partition sizes, types, block sizes cause problems.
In most cases you are better off using `cp -rp` or `tar`.
If you are trying to clone a drive that has a bootable linux operating system, you do not need to use `dd` there are better ways.

Comment: I am trying to clone my windows 8.1 disk, If I was to just use cp wouldn't it ignore the Boot records and the OS setup? I do agree that dd is not effiencet here - especially since the 500GB laptop HD im copying, I have only used around 35GB(mostly OS files and few music files), therefore I am copying/writing 465GB byte by byte empty space...

Comment: i figured you were trying to clone a bootable disk with an operating system on it.  If this were a linux operating system having an EFI boot partition that is formatted as FAT32, then it is easy to clone.  Realize there are 2 different methods of booting and boot records- EFI and MBR.  EFI is better because it is easier, when dealing with MBR you have to handle the first 500 bytes of the disk which makes things hard, but in linux and when using GRUB you can use a linux install disk and run an auto fix to have GRUB fix the MBR on the disk.

Comment: Windows 8, and windows 7 also, can do EFI boot, but only if your motherboard supports EFI and you have it chosen versus legacy boot (which is MBR).  Microsoft does not make cloning easy because of piracy, and i am not up to date on cloning bootable MS drives.  I suggest you use a software package to do it, such as macrium reflect or Aomei backupper

Comment: note: a simple dd of one disk to another for cloning, if it boots under EFI, will still have problems because of things like mounting a drive by disk-id.  your new hard drive will have a new disk id, but your dd (disk dump) from your original drive all the files will reference the original hard disk id.  so you have to change it somehow otherwise it will not boot.  cloning software will handle this in regards to however microsoft windows handles identifying drives in the boot process.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, it appears my Win 8.1 Installation uses MBR. So in my 500 laptop HD i end up with 300mb reserved for the MBR and the rest for the OS and free space. Do you know of an easier way instead of copying all the empty space? Theoretically I am wondering if I can copy just the MBR part, the OS files, and perhaps the metadata for the structure of the disk volumes?